# Json deserialization is failing

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am attempting to deserialize a JSON string to an object.

The exception being thrown is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'APIServer.Models.UserProfileModel'.

This is the JSON string:

```
"id": "b483c490-8d5a-4247-b3d3-8eb7cc4208bd",
"firstName": "Jeremy",
"lastName": "Krasin",
"gender": null,
"birthDate": null,
"homeCountry": null,
"publicName": null,
"self": {
    "href": "http://localhost:54253/api/userprofiles/b483c490-8d5a-4247-b3d3-8eb7cc4208bd",
    "relations": [
        "collections"
    ],
    "method": "GET",
    "routeName": null,
    "routeValues": null
},
"href": "http://localhost:54253/api/userprofiles/b483c490-8d5a-4247-b3d3-8eb7cc4208bd",
"relations": [
    "collections"
],
"method": "GET",
"routeName": null,
"routeValues": null
```

This is the class I am trying to deserialize into:

```
public class UserProfileModel : BaseModel<UserProfileModel> {

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public string BirthDate { get; set; }

    public string HomeCountry { get; set; }

    public string PublicName { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

This is the line of code that is attempting the deserialization:

```
return (T) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(RestClient.Execute(aRequest).Content);
```

I verified that `T` is the following type:

```
APIServer.Models.UserProfileModel
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the type when you call `DeserializeObject` like this:

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(RestClient.Execute(aRequest).Content);
                                    ^^^
```

When you do not specify the type, `DeserializeObject` will return a `JObject`, which cannot be cast to your `APIServer.Models.UserProfileModel`.  This is why you are getting an error.